# Changing Background Image with nth-child selectors. (SASS)

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Converting a site to SASS for some practice. Obviolsuly I could do this without nesting, but I think this should work. I would like the class property (.side_image) to switch to a new PNG every section DIV. However this code is only going to the first child element therefore is not cycling through the images. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

```
section {

  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;

  .side_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    filter: invert(1);

    &:nth-child(1) {
      background: url("../img/ux_ixd.png");
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: url("../img/resume.png");
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      background: url("../img/ux_ixd.png");
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (that the `:nth-child(n)` should refer to the `section`), this should work. It counts the section element and refers to the image in there. The common parameters were moved to the general `.side-image` rule. (You didn't post any HTML, so I am not sure about your structure).

```
section {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  .side_image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    filter: invert(1);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
   }
   &:nth-child(1) .side_image {
    background: url("../img/ux_ixd.png");
   }
   &:nth-child(2) .side_image {
    background: url("../img/resume.png");
   }
   &:nth-child(3) .side_image {
    background: url("../img/ux_ixd.png");
   }
}
```

Comment: ```<section>
      <div class="side_image">
      </div>
      <div class="container">
      </div>
</section>```

Comment: Which part of that is repeated?

Comment: you should edit your question, not my answer to add missing code... But even your (rejected) edit still didn't make clear which part of the HTML code is repeated

Comment: If the HTML whole code you posted in your comment abobe is repeated, the CSS code in my answer should do what you are asking for. The `nth-child` rules refer to the `section` elements, and the `.side-image` elements are child elements of the `section` elements.